# What is the difference between Shor's algorithm for factoring and Shor's algorithm for logarithms?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, factoring, quantum-cryptography, shors-algorithm

There is a paper from Peter W. Shor from 1994:  [*Algorithms for Quantum Computation: Discrete Logarithms and Factoring*](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/365700), and I have a question about it and the algorithms presented.

For integer factoring problem, Shor's algorithm is working as a fast period finder for function `f(x) = a^x mod N`, where semiprime N is equal to p*q, a is fixed and all possible exponents `x` are quantumly computed. Then, Shor uses Simon's algorithm to find period `r` of `f(x)` such that `f(x) = f(x+r)` . With 0.5 probability, the output of quantum scheme `r` will be the even, and `a^(r/2)` will be the non-trivial square root of `1 mod N`. Having such root we can easily crack `N` to `p` and `q`. (If there is something wrong with this description, please comment. The simple quantum circuit is
[here](https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v414/n6866/fig_tab/414883a_F1.html).

But how does Shor's algorithm for the [discrete logarithm problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) work? There is only prime number `P` (and generator `g`), so we can't factor it into something having a square root. I'm even not sure that there will be any nontrivial square root in the `mod p` field.

The task for discrete logarithm is: given some `x`, equal to `x = g^r mod p`, with `g` and `p` known, find the `r`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the basic idea of Shor's algorithm for the discrete logarithm problem is reasonably simple.

Assume (as in Section 4 *Discrete Log: the easy case* of Shor's paper) that you have an efficient quantum algorithm for the Fourier transform. Then, applying this Fourier transform twice (once for $a$ and once for $b$) on a quantum superposition of values $g^a\cdot x^{-b}$ and measuring yields a pair $(c,d)$ with $d\equiv -cr\pmod{p-1}$. Thus, you can recover $r$ (if the *gcd* of $c$ and $p-1$ is $1$) directly with a simple division modulo $p-1$. [If the *gcd* is a small number it is also easy to conclude]

Unfortunately, doing this Fourier transform directly is only easy when $p-1$ is smooth (which is an uninteresting case since dlogs are easy with a classical computer in that case) and technicalities arise because of this. These technicalities involve replacing the Fourier transform modulo $p-1$ by a Fourier transform modulo $q,$ where $q$ is smooth and not too far from $p-1$.  A similar technique is used for factoring: it is simpler than the general discrete logarithm case because a single application of the Fourier transform is enough in that case.